# jqGrid get row data on select

Tags: jqgrid

I need to peices of data from the row on select, so I can send it off.  I am getting 'false' on the teacher and student vars.  TeacherId is the Id column for the grid.

```
   onSelectRow: function () {
        var $grid = $("#student-grid");
        var rowData = $grid.jqGrid('getRowData', 'selrow');
        var teacher = $grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowData, 'teacherId');
        var student = $grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowData, 'studentId');

        alert('student num is: ' + student + ' and the teacher num is: ' + teacher);

    }
```

Edit to add more info:

```
     colModel: [
         { name: 'studentId', index: 'studentId', key: false, hidden: true },
         { name: 'teacherId', index: 'teacherId', key: true, hidden: true },
... (other columns)
]
```

Yes I am using loadonce: true and both using datatype JSON.

Comment: You should include the definition of the columns in `colModel`. Which names (the value of `name` property) have the columns? You write about `TeacherId` and `Id` columns, but you use `teacherId` (another case) and `studentId` in the code. Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` option?

Comment: I was able to get the data by changing 'getRowData' to 'getGridParam'.